# Aggregating a new variable when the group changes

Tags: r, dplyr

this should be fairly simple but I just can't get my head around it.

I have the following dataframe,

```r
df <- data.frame(Type = c(rep('type1',3),rep('type2',2),rep('type3',3)))
```

I want to aggregate, and then start with a 1-value, and increase it once the group changes, having the following output:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(Type = c(rep('typea',3),rep('typeb',2),rep('typec',3)), new_var = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3))
```

Long story short, I am looking to count groups and add them to the right of the dataframe.

Comment: `df$new_var <- match(df$Type, unique(df$Type))`

Comment: Added the dplyr tag as it is an ideal solution to do this within that package

Answer (score 1):

In [`?dplyr::context`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html) (not the first place I might look when search for this, but ... I searched for related topics and found that help page), they list several helper functions that are available within a `dplyr` verb, and can identity some properties of the current group or such. Included in this list of context functions:

- `n()`
- `cur_data()` and `cur_data_all()`
- `cur_group()` (same class as the grouping variable(s)) and `cur_group_id()` (integer)
- `cur_group_rows()`
- `cur_column()` (useful within `across` actions)

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  mutate(new_var = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 2
#   Type  new_var
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1 type1       1
# 2 type1       1
# 3 type1       1
# 4 type2       2
# 5 type2       2
# 6 type3       3
# 7 type3       3
# 8 type3       3
```